# Twilio.Device.setup throws error

Tags: twilio, audiocontext

I am developing BrowserPhone by twilio.js, version is 1.4.20.

When token expired, I am handling Twilio.Device.offline(),
and regenerate token and re-setup Twilio.Device.

After 6 times re-setup, then, Twilio.js throw error.

`*Failed* to construct 'AudioContext': The number of hardware contexts provided (6) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (6).`

How can I prevent this error?

I'm using these code.

```
Twilio.Device.offline((device) => {
if (navigator.onLine) {
    Twilio.Device.destroy();
    Twilio.Device.instance = null;
    getToken(device._clientName);
}

const getToken = (identity) => {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseurl + '/token/get',
    data: {'identity': identity}
})
.done((data) => {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    Twilio.Device.setup(data.token, {
        closeProtection: true
    });
};
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to handle the offline event, regenerate the token and run setup again?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I'm using these code.

```
  Twilio.Device.offline((device) => {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        Twilio.Device.destroy();
        Twilio.Device.instance = null;
        const client_name = device._clientName;
        getToken(client_name);
      }
```

```
const getToken = (identity) => {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseurl + '/token/get',
    data: {'identity': identity}
  })
    .done((data) => {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    Twilio.Device.setup(data.token, {
      closeProtection: true
    });
};

```

Comment: Sorry, still looking into this at the moment. Which browser are you experiencing this in?

Comment: Hey, is this application running in more than one browser tab at the same time too? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm developing Chrome Extension.Application is single device running.I think twilio.js in L.86 every time instance AudioContext makes exception.I tried Twilio.Device.destroy() before setup, but exception still thrown:(